# PHP & Regex - find specific string inside a title(string)

Tags: php, regex, string

I got stored in array months of the year in italian like this:

```
$array = [
"gennaio" => "1",
"febbraio" => "2",
"marzo" => "3",
"aprile" => "4",
"maggio" => "5",
"giugno" => "6",
"luglio" => "7",
"agosto" => "8",
"settembre" => "9",
"ottobre" => "10",
"novembre" => "11",
"dicembre" => "12"
];
```

Also I got this titles also:

```
$title1 = "Nota_382_del_16 marzo_2016.pdf";
$title2 = "OCDPC 382 del 16_agosto_2016.pdf";
$title3 = "OCDPC_382_del 16 _agosto 2016.pdf";
$title4 = "OCDPC_382_dal 16agosto 2016.pdf";
$title5 = "OCDPC_382 dall 16luglio2016.pdf";
$title6 = "OCDPC_382 da 16agosto_2016.pdf";
$title7 = "OCDPC_382_del_16_settembre 2016.pdf";
$title8 = "OCDPC_382 di 16 _agosto.2016.pdf";
$title9 = "OCDPC_382_del-16-agosto 2016.pdf";
$title10 = "Dipartimento OCDPC 382_del-16-agosto-2016.pdf";
$title11 = "OCDPC_382 dall'16-febbraio-2016.pdf";
$title12 = "OCDPC_382 dal'16-agosto-2016 - Dipartimentocivile.pdf";
```

In each title I want to get the full date like `16 settembre 2016` and than format it like `16/09/2016`.

I have no problems on formatting the date, but my main issue is using the correct `regex` to catch it and than changing the month name to numbers. For changing months on number I can manage it somehow with a `switch` statement.

Any type of help will be appreciated!

Edit: Until now I have manage it like this:

`(?<![^\W_])?del?\s*\K\d+.?\d+.?20[0-2][0-9]`

The actual regex catches the date when the month is referred by number and not the name.

But this is a very specific case and I'm not an `regex` expert...

Comment: I got a regex code: `(?<![^\W_])?del?\s*\K\d+.?\d+.?20[0-2][0-9]` but will not work for this case! I'm trying to get some help in here, and I will need many days to have the solution and I think stackoverflow exist just for this purpose. Helping each other.

Comment: I think all you need is `(?<!\d)\d{1,2}[\W_]*\p{L}+[\W_]*\d{4}(?!\d)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/afCCgo/1))

Comment: Then you may further enhance with groups, `(?<!\d)(\d{1,2})[\W_]*(\p{L}+)[\W_]*(\d{4})(?!\d)`, or with named groups, `(?<!\d)(?P<day>\d{1,2})[\W_]*(?P<month>\p{L}+)[\W_]*(?P<year>\d{4})(?!\d)`

Comment: Post the answer to be accepted. I'm sure this question will be handy for many other devs.

Comment: Presumably a typo... But your array should have commas not semi-colons after each item!

Comment: Yeah just a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Regex

Although this has already been answered by [@WiktorStribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66118625/2573622) I'd suggest a slightly different take on the regex...

```
/(\d\d?)[._ -]*([a-z]+)[._ -]*(\d{4})/i
/                                           : Pattern delimiter
 (\d\d?)                                    : Matches the day (1 or 2 numbers) and assigns to a capture group
        [._ -]*                             : Mathces a delimiter 0 or more times
               ([a-z]+)                     : Matches the textual month and assigns to a capture group
                       [._ -]*              : Mathces a delimiter 0 or more times
                              (\d{4})       : Matches the year (4 numbers) and assigns to a capture group
                                     /      : Pattern delimiter
                                      i     : Makes the regex case insensitive, just in case
```

...which is a bit easier to read and understand. It's also slightly more specific when it comes to the date delimiters (or lack of) so you're less likely to get clashes.

### Code Example

```
$months = [
    "gennaio" => "1",
    "febbraio" => "2",
    "marzo" => "3",
    "aprile" => "4",
    "maggio" => "5",
    "giugno" => "6",
    "luglio" => "7",
    "agosto" => "8",
    "settembre" => "9",
    "ottobre" => "10",
    "novembre" => "11",
    "dicembre" => "12",
];




$titles = [
    "Nota_382_del_16 marzo_2016.pdf",
    "OCDPC 382 del 16_agosto_2016.pdf",
    "OCDPC_382_del 16 _agosto 2016.pdf",
    "OCDPC_382_dal 16agosto 2016.pdf",
    "OCDPC_382 dall 16luglio2016.pdf",
    "OCDPC_382 da 16agosto_2016.pdf",
    "OCDPC_382_del_16_settembre 2016.pdf",
    "OCDPC_382 di 16 _agosto.2016.pdf",
    "OCDPC_382_del-16-agosto 2016.pdf",
    "Dipartimento OCDPC 382_del-16-agosto-2016.pdf",
    "OCDPC_382 dall'16-febbraio-2016.pdf",
    "OCDPC_382 dal'16-agosto-2016 - Dipartimentocivile.pdf",
];

foreach ($titles as $title) {
    preg_match('/(\d\d?)[._ -]*([a-z]+)[._ -]*(\d{4})/i', $title, $dateParts);
    echo $dateParts[1], "/", $months[strtolower($dateParts[2])], "/", $dateParts[3], " ", PHP_EOL ;
}


/* Potentially easier to read version:

foreach($titles as $title){
    preg_match('/(\d\d?)[._ -]*([a-z]+)[._ -]*(\d{4})/i', $title, $dateParts);

    list(, $day, $month, $year) = $dateParts;
    $month = $months[strtolower($month)];

    echo "$day/$month/$year", PHP_EOL;
}

*/
```

Output:

```
16/3/2016
16/8/2016
16/8/2016
16/8/2016
16/7/2016
16/8/2016
16/9/2016
16/8/2016
16/8/2016
16/8/2016
16/2/2016
16/8/2016
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```php
(?<!\d)\d{1,2}[\W_]*\p{L}+[\W_]*\d{4}(?!\d)
(?<!\d)(\d{1,2})[\W_]*(\p{L}+)[\W_]*(\d{4})(?!\d)                          // With numbered groups
(?<!\d)(?P<day>\d{1,2})[\W_]*(?P<month>\p{L}+)[\W_]*(?P<year>\d{4})(?!\d)  // With named groups
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tFM7uh/1). *Details*:

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `[\W_]*` - zero or more non-alphanumeric chars
- `\p{L}+` - one or more any Unicode letters
- `[\W_]*` - zero or more non-alphanumeric chars
- `\d{4}` - four digits (`\d{2}(?:\d{2})?` can be used if there can be 2-digit year)
- `(?!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

In PHP, you can use it like

```php
if (preg_match('~(?<!\d)(?P<day>\d{1,2})[\W_]*(?P<month>\p{L}+)[\W_]*(?P<year>\d{4})(?!\d)~u', $string, $match)) {
  echo $match["day"] . PHP_EOL;
  echo $match["month"] . PHP_EOL;
  echo $match["year"];
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/fWqMC).